# Laravel how to get file extension from path

Tags: laravel

I've file with name `temp` in `tempimages` folder. This is the only file in the folder. The name is constant but the extension can by any image extension.

I am getting the `extension` this way.

```
$files = File::files(public_path('tempimages'));
    if(sizeof($files) > 0){
        $ext = $files[0]->getExtension();
    }
```

it is working but I want to know if I am doing it right or there is a better way like some function that get `path` and `file-name-without-extension`, and returns `extension`.

Note: I am not getting the file in `request` in this `controller`. It already exists in the `tempimages` and here I am just accessing it.

Comment: The `getExtension()` method is the one I would go with. You can shorten your code to something like `$extension = collect(File::files(public_path('tempimages')))->first()?->getExtension()`, which will return `'png'` (or whatever the extension of the Image file is), or `null` if there is no file.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to get the file extension from a file in the 'tempimages' folder using Laravel's `File` class is valid. However, if you want to simplify the code, you can use the `pathinfo` function in PHP, which doesn't require using Laravel's `File` class. Here's how you can do it:

```php
$filePath = public_path('tempimages/temp');

if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    $extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Now $extension contains the file extension
} else {
    // Handle the case where the file doesn't exist
}
```

This code will directly extract the file extension from the given file path without having to use Laravel's `File` class. It's a more general PHP approach that works in Laravel as well.